# Filter by checkbox with seo friendly url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I want to add filtering (checkboxes) to our houses listing page. I was thinking to do it by ajax in case of good usabilty, but what is also important that the URL structure is SEO friendly for seo purpose.

An example:

- theme checkbox is "nearthesea". The url is domain.com/houses/nearthesea
- theme checkbox is "idealfortwo". The url is domain.com/houses/idealfortwo
- amenity checkbox is "wifi" The url must be domain.com/houses/idealfortwo/wifi

Has someone ideas, links, posts ect to set this up?

Comment: How 'deep'  will the URLs be, i.e. do you want more than two filters per URL?  Do you envision:  domain.com/houses/idealfortwo/wifi/pool/goodschools ?

Comment: yep..or more. I have 5 theme categories like, nearthecoast, idealfortwo, family ect. they all have amenities like bbq, wifi, oven ect. When a visitor visits a theme/landingpage they have the possibilty the filer by amenities or change the categories (checkbox)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no real way to do that, i.e. define a route with an undefined number of path components.  You could choose a maximum number, and define a series of routes, like

```
get '/houses/:f1' => 'houses#index'
get '/houses/:f1/:f2' =>'houses#index'
...
get '/houses/:f1/:f2/:f3/:f4/:f5/:f6' =>'houses#index'
```

But that would get ugly quick,  I'd recommend to go with a URL scheme like this:

```
get '/houses' => 'houses#index'
```

Then your URL's could look like:

```
/houses?filter=goodschool,bbq,northeast
```

Then in your index action:

```
def index
  if params[:filter]
     filters = params[:filter].split(",")
     filters.each do |f|
       # do something with each term in the filter, I have no idea
     end
     @houses = House.where(.....???)
  else
     @houses = House.all
  end
end
```

It won't yield the SEO friendly URLs you're after, but I'm not sure just how this would affect SEO in your situation.